# Reactive selection of a dataset in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dataset

I am building a R Shiny app where I have different datasets and I do a plot of one or another depending of the choice of the user.

I would like to change from a dataset to the second one when I make this choice but it is currently not working. I have tried with `reactive`, `observeEvent` and `reactiveValues` but I could not figure it out.

Here is a simplified code of what I have done.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
             fluidRow(
               column(4,
                      wellPanel(
                        selectInput('dataset', 'Dataset', c('Synthetic 2M', 'Synthetic 4M'), 
                                    selected = 'Synthetic 2M'))
               ),
              column(8,
                     plotlyOutput('plot_result')
                     )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #data load
  data2M <-data.frame(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,0,1),floor(runif(100,1,10)))
  data4M <-data.frame(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,0,1),floor(runif(100,1,10)))
  data <- data2M

  #dataset choice
  reactive({
    if (input$dataset == 'Synthetic 2M'){
      data <- data2M
    } else if (input$dataset == 'Synthetic 4M') {
      data <- data4M
    }
    else {}
  })

  #plot
  output$plot_result <- renderPlotly({
      names(data) <- c("x","y","cluster")
      plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~cluster, text = data$cluster,
              type = "scatter", mode = "markers", hovertemplate = paste(
                "Coordinate: %{x},%{y}<br>",
                "Cluster: %{text}<br>"))})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope any of you have an idea how to make it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reactive is a function. You have to store it then call it with `()`. Be carreful with the name of your variables between functions and variables.

Here is one way to do it:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           wellPanel(
             selectInput('dataset', 'Dataset', c('Synthetic 2M', 'Synthetic 4M'),
                         selected = 'Synthetic 2M'))
    ),
    column(8,
           plotlyOutput('plot_result')
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #data load
  data2M <-data.frame(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,0,1),floor(runif(100,1,10)))
  data4M <-data.frame(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,0,1),floor(runif(100,1,10)))
  data <- data2M

  #dataset choice
  data_plot <- reactive({
    if (input$dataset == 'Synthetic 2M'){
      return(data2M)
    } else if (input$dataset == 'Synthetic 4M') {
      return(data4M)
    } else {
      return(data)
    }
  })

  #plot
  output$plot_result <- renderPlotly({
    d <- data_plot()
    names(d) <- c("x","y","cluster")
    plot_ly(d, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~cluster, text = data$cluster,
            type = "scatter", mode = "markers", hovertemplate = paste(
              "Coordinate: %{x},%{y}<br>",
              "Cluster: %{text}<br>"))})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```